# When selecting a row on a tableview using the search bar in swift it doesn't do the desired function

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, uisearchbar

I made a table view which allows the user to search through with a search bar. When selecting a row without the search everything works fine. However, when using the search bar, it doesn't perform the desired function. E.g. let's say I have an array ["dog","cat","horse"], and I search "c", cat will come up, but if I press it the function that occurs when you press "dog" will occur. I think it's because the cat row is 2, but when I search it becomes 1, which is the row of "dog".

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by using 
`let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
let currentCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath!)!
print(currentCell.textLabel!.text)`to find the actual title of the row rather than just it's value. Thanks for the help anyways.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to save the indexpath of all of the cells in your tableview, possibly in an array. That way, when the table is re-arranged, you can still call `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` or other related methods with the real indexpath.

EDIT: You can implement the `cellForRowAt` method for your tableView:

```
var indexPathsArray: [Int] = []
...

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    indexPathsArray.append(indexPath.row)
}
```

Comment: How could you save the indexPath of the rows in the tableView?

Comment: How would you do this?

Answer (score 0):

Hello @user8802333 You need to take a Bool variable like isSearch. If searching is performed then it should be true else false. In `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` put an if condition if isSearch is true then pass values from search result array otherwise pass values from default array. I hope I am clear to you what I want to say.